# Using object storage with authorization for a web app

Tags: amazon-s3, web, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, minio

I'm contributing to developping a web (front+back) application, which uses OpenID Connect (with auth0) for authentication & authorization.

The web app needs authentication to access some public & some restricted information (restriction are per-user or depending on certain group-related rules).

We want to provide a upload/download features for documents such as .pdf, and we have implemented minIO (pretty similar to AWS S3) for public documents.

However, we can't wrap ou heads around restricted-access files :

- should we implement OIDC on minIO for users to access directly the buckets but with temporary access tokens, allowing for fine-grained authorization policy
- or should the back-office be the only one to have keys to minIO and be the intermediary between the object storage and users ?

Looking for good practices here, thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, since PDF docs are web static content unless they contain sensitive data. I would aim to separate secured (API) and non-secured (web) concerns on this one.

**UNSECURED RESOURCES**

If there is no security involved, connecting to a bucket from the front end makes sense. The bucket contents can also be distributed to a content delivery network, for best global performance. The PDF can be considered a web resource.

**SECURED RESOURCES**

Requests for these need to be treated as an API request, if a PDF doc contains sensitive data. APIs should receive an access token and enforce access to documents via scopes and claims.

You might use a Documents API for this. The implementation might still connect to a bucket, but this might be a different bucket that the browser does not have access to.

**SUMMARY**

This type of solution is often clearer if you think in terms of URL design. Eg the front end might have 2 document URLs:

- publicDocs
- secureDocs

By default I would treat docs that users upload as secure, unless they select an upload option such as `make public`.